# Task.WaitAll, get all exceptions and individual task durations

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, stopwatch

I am developing a utility which will execute multiple SqlCommands in parallel using ExecuteNonQueryAsync. The utility should only return when all requests are completed, so I am using WaitAll.

As it happens, this utility is a SQL CLR stored procedure. **This precludes the use of Task.Run()**.

I want to capture all of the individual exceptions which occur, which seems to be working fine. I am now trying to add the ability to also get the elapsed duration of each individual task within the array.

Here is the core of the code **without** any elapsed time information:

```cs
// the commands array has been populated with an array of strings (TSQL statemements to execute)
Task<int>[] tasks = new Task<int>[commands.Length];

try {
    for (int i = 0; i < commands.Length; i++) {
        // executeSQL is an asyc method which makes the appropriate connection and returns await ExecuteNonQueryAsync
        tasks[i] = executeSql(commands[i], connectionString, (int)commandTimeout);
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
} catch (AggregateException) {
    // exceptions reported in GetResults
} finally { 
    //GetResults builds a datatable of { command, result, exception text }
    var results = GetResults(commands, tasks);
}
```

Now, I'm struggling to figure out how to get the elapsed time of each individual ExecuteNonQueryAsync request.

My first thought was to create an array of stopwatches, and add a stopwatch parameter to the executeSQL call, and then pass the watches array to the GetResults function:

```cs
Task<int>[] tasks = new Task<int>[commands.Length];
Stopwatch[] watches = new Stopwatch[commands.Length];

try {
    for (int i = 0; i < commands.Length; i++) {
        tasks[i] = executeSql(commands[i], connectionString, (int)commandTimeout, watches[i]);
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
} catch (AggregateException) {
    // exceptions reported in finally
} finally {
    var results = GetResults(commands, tasks, watches);
}
```

I can start the stopwatch just before calling ExecuteNonQueryAsync inside the executeSQL function. But when can I stop it?

This is as far as I've gotten trying to solve the problem. I thought I would add a continuation to stop the stopwatch, and wait on the continuation. But this code is not valid (*Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'*)

```cs
var tasks = new Task<int>[commands.Length];
var watches = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch[commands.Length];

try {
    for (int i = 0; i < commands.Length; i++) {
        tasks[i] = executeSql(commands[i], connectionString, (int)commandTimeout, watches[i]).ContinueWith(
            t => {
                watches[i].Stop();
                return t;
            },
            TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent
        ).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
} catch (AggregateException) {
    // ...
```

Comment: Assign the `Task` to a variable, `ConfigureAwait` on that variable on the next line, and then add it to your array. Because you have written it all on one line, you are trying to add the return value to `ConfigureAwait` to your `tasks` array.

Comment: Cheers Colin. I am finding it really confusing trying to determine when the language "magically" sorts things out for you, and when it does not, when using async.

I mean, what you said seems perfectly obvious on the one hand, but on the other hand async function which returns a Task<T> can't actually return a Task<T>, and an async which returns a Task<T> can't actually be assigned to a Task<T>. Eg:
    `watch.Start(); Task<int> t = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    watch.Stop();
    return t;`


Is invalid!.

Comment: It's not assignable because you're awaiting the `Task` and then trying to assign the result (which is `int`) of that to `Task<int>`, when it's actually just `int` because `await` has waited for the job to finish and thus unwrapped the `.Result` object. What you'd actually want is `watch.Start(); Task<int> t = cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ContinueWith(task => { watch.Stop() return task.Result; }); t.ConfigureAwait(false); return (await t);` Parenthesis aren't needed on `await` but added for clarity.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to get that the language "magic" is realy only in the Taskifying of results. I still don't quite understand how I can assign, say, an int as a result, return the int, and then somehow the language figures out that if an exception occurs this int somehow "carries" the exception, because it's been taskified. That's really confusing. But in any case, while I think what you have there would work I have achieved the same result slightly differently.

Adding answer now

Comment: It's not the `Result` that carries the exception, it's the `Exception` property of the `Task` class. The unwrapping, or calling of the `Result` property is where the logic of throwing an exception, or returning the value, resides.

Comment: Yep, I think I grok the idea behind it: the "await" unwraps the task to an int, which is why you have to assign the return value of the function which returns a Task of int to an int rather than a task of int. But if an exception does occur then the awaiting function, which it itself asynch, is still going to return a task, and so the exception is available to the caller. It sort of makes sense to me, but the magic of the state machine is jut a bit weird :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use https://sharplab.io to write some asynchronous awaited code and you'll see what it compiles to, and it's calls to `SetResult(T)` or `SetException(Exception)` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer was that the "simple" solution actually does work, although I expected it wouldn't.

Below is my new definition for the executeSQL function, and how it is being called.

The bit that was making my brain hurt was the exception handling. I figured that if the language itself was turning my results into tasks, and magically attaching exceptions to those results in the task when needed, then, *surely*, if I simply threw an exception myself the normal way (as per the finally block below) something unexpected would happen. (And the fact that ExecuteNonQueryAsync returns a Task<int>, but I have to assign the result to an int - not a Task<int> - is still really weird to me and I *do not* like it.)

But nope! It just seems to work.

```cs
static async internal Task<int> executeSql(string tsql, string connectionString, int commandTimeout, System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch) {
    int i = -1;
    Exception ex = null;
    try {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
            con.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("set xact_abort on;" + tsql, con)) {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
                watch.Start();
                i = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ex = e;
    } finally {
        watch.Stop();
        if (ex != null) { throw ex; }
    }
    return i;
}

// ....

var tasks = new Task<int>[commands.Length];
var watches = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch[commands.Length];

try {
    for (int i = 0; i < commands.Length; i++) {
        watches[i] = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        tasks[i] = executeSql(commands[i], connectionString, (int)commandTimeout, watches[i]);
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
} catch (AggregateException) { 
    // ...
```

Comment: Slight modification, you don't need to catch the exception and rethrow because the `finally` block will always be executed, so you can simply compress your code down to a `try-finally`. Using `throw ex` is also not a great idea because it doesn't preserve the stack trace of the actual error, and instead your stack trace will begin at your calling method - and end at `executeSql`. The correct syntax to use, to preserve the stack trace, is just `throw`, but can only be used within a `catch` block.

Comment: Another comment, if you're using asynchronous programming then you should use `Task.WhenAll(Task[])` instead which you can use `await` with, whereas `Task.WaitAll(Task[])` is a thread blocking operation.

Comment: Good point about try/catch/finally vs try/finally. As it happens I am actually deliberately cutting down the stack trace, should have mentioned that.

Comment: Regarding waitall vs whenall - this is actually the code for a sql clr stored procedure, which can't be awaited from within TSQL, hence the WaitAll. But yeah, I have seen your advice here in several places 
 (in my few-weeks-long cram session on async...) and will definitely remember that when using async more generally! You're a fountain of good info!